# Return 3 dimensional array

Tags: c

I have an starting array called matrix, and now I want to manipulate it with my function calc_Matrix. The result I want to save in a new char array and now I want to manipulate it again:

```
char calc_Matrix(char matrix[][2][2])
{
  char new_matrix[2][2][2];
  //manipulate matrix -> new_matrix
  return new_matrix[2][2][2];
}

int main()
{
  char matrix[2][2][2]=..... //my starting matrix
  char new_matrix1[2][2][2];
  char new_matrix2[2][2][2];

  new_matrix1[2][2][2]=calc_matrix(matrix);
  new_matrix2[2][2][2]=calc_matrix(new_matrix1);
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: `return new_matrix[2][2][2];` return a char, not array. and Array out of range.

Comment: As you are taking `new_matrix1[2][2][2];` you can not return index `[2][2][2]`. its index should be `0` or `1`.

Comment: You have to understand how arrays work in C before you attempt anything like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return arrays like that - pass the output array as a parameter instead, e.g.

```
void calc_Matrix(char in_matrix[][2][2],    // input matrix
                 char out_matrix[][2][2])   // output matrix
{
    // manipulate in_matrix -> out_matrix
}

int main()
{
    char matrix[2][2][2]= { ... };
    char new_matrix1[2][2][2];
    char new_matrix2[2][2][2];

    calc_matrix(matrix, new_matrix1);      // matrix -> new_matrix1
    calc_matrix(new_matrix1, new_matrix2); // new_matrix1 -> new_matrix2

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a pointer to a 3D array but:

1. You need a typedef or an ugly declaration (see edit)
2. You need to reserve space (using `malloc`) for this new 3D array
3. You need to pass the `sizeof` the 3D array

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char (*pmatrix)[2][2];

pmatrix calc_Matrix(char matrix[][2][2], size_t size)
{
    char (*new_matrix)[2][2];

    new_matrix = malloc(size);
    if (new_matrix == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //manipulate matrix -> new_matrix
    return new_matrix;
}


int main(void)
{
    char matrix[2][2][2] = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}};
    char (*new_matrix)[2][2] = calc_Matrix(matrix, sizeof(matrix));

    free(new_matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
typedef char (*pmatrix)[2][2];

pmatrix calc_Matrix(char matrix[][2][2], size_t size)
{
    ...
}
```

can be replaced with

```
char (*calc_Matrix(char matrix[][2][2], size_t size))[2][2]
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You performed in the same manner that it be wrapped in struct. (It is desirable in this case it is a small size.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct matrix {
    char m[2][2][2];
} Matrix;

Matrix calc_Matrix(Matrix mat){
    Matrix new_matrix;
    //manipulate matrix -> new_matrix
    new_matrix.m[0][0][0] = mat.m[0][0][0] + 1;
    return new_matrix;
}

int main(){
    Matrix matrix;
    Matrix new_matrix1;
    Matrix new_matrix2;

    matrix.m[0][0][0] = 'a';
    new_matrix1 = calc_Matrix(matrix);
    new_matrix2 = calc_Matrix(new_matrix1);
    printf("%c\n", new_matrix2.m[0][0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to pass the entire struct, I suggest `Matrix calc_Matrix(Matrix *mat){...}` and `new_matrix1 = calc_Matrix(&matrix);`, in this case `sizeof(matrix) = sizeof(&matrix)` but on larger arrays its a waste of space.